# The $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable returns my visited website's URL

Tags: php, http-referer

Some links redirect to my website but the PHP variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] executed on my website keeps on returning my own website's URL no matter the referer. Do I have anything to configure server-side?

Comment: Your website's URL will always be the referrer to a given website since you *referred* the user to that other website.

Comment: No that's actually the refered website which returns its own URL, not the referer's one! User comes from website A to website B, and the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable run on website B returns its own url.

Comment: Edited the question's body which was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you don't need to configure anything to get the referrer.  If you're seeing something different than you expect, I suggest using a debugging http proxy like fiddler to watch the http request headers as they're sent.  You may have a redirect on your own site that is happening before you're checking the referer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in the page that is being linked to, or are you calling it in a script the you call from the page being linked to? If it is the latter, then $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] would contain the page calling the script, that page being the page that was linked to.

In short, where are you calling $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your domain from the equation if it is the referrer

```
if (stripos($url, 'yourdomain') !== false)
```